# access_token from google-sign-in-web

Tags: flutter, google-signin

Since [google-sign-in-web](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in_web) now separates Authentication from Authorization, how can I access the access_token that is required for firebase_auth.

It is no longer available through the GoogleSignInAuthentication object.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as auth;
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
...
const List<String> scopes = <String>[
  'profile',
  'email',
  'openid',
];
...
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: scopes);
GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
...
debugPrint('googleAuth.accessToken: ${googleAuth.accessToken}');
debugPrint('googleAuth.idToken: ${googleAuth.idToken}');
final auth.AuthCredential credential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
  accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
  idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
);
final auth.UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

It actually shows up in the browser console logs, but I don't see how to access it from the dart code:

```
[GSI_LOGGER-TOKEN_CLIENT]: Handling response. {"access_token":"ya29.a0AbVbY6MRHT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

access_token is not needed for the web implementation through flutter:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/federated-auth#web